# socket inputstream corrupted while using BOX java sdk

Tags: java, sockets, box-api

I am trying to execute the HelloWorld.java (downloaded from https://github.com/box/box-java-sdk-v2)

getting error

> com.box.boxjavalibv2.exceptions.BoxServerException: {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Auth code doesn't exist or is invalid for the client"}

looks like auth code is corrupted. I tried setting encoding explicitly while reading input steam, it did not work.

Has anyone experienced the same problem? pls let me know as how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's working now. I changed redirect uri from https to http